# setting WKInterfacePicker height with animation selects arbitrary item

Tags: swift, animation, watchkit, watchos-2

In a watchOS 2 interface controller, I am showing a button and a WKInterfacePicker.

When the user presses the button, the picker hides and shows with animation. The visual effect works nicely.

This has an unintended side effect: setting the height with animation changes the selected Item and I found no way around it so far.

```
func setDurationPickerVisibility(duration: NSTimeInterval) {
    print ("self.durationPickerHidden=\(self.durationPickerHidden)")
    animateWithDuration(duration) {
        if self.durationPickerHidden {
            self.durationPicker.resignFocus()
            self.durationPicker.setHeight(0.0)
            self.durationPicker.setHidden(self.durationPickerHidden)
        } else {
            self.durationPicker.setHeight(self.durationPickerHeigth)
            print ("animation setting durationPicker Index to \(self.durationPickerIndex)")
            self.durationPicker.setSelectedItemIndex(self.durationPickerIndex)
        }
    }
    if !self.durationPickerHidden {
        print ("direct setting durationPicker Index to \(self.durationPickerIndex)")
        self.durationPicker.setSelectedItemIndex(durationPickerIndex)
        self.durationPicker.setHidden(self.durationPickerHidden)
        self.durationPicker.focus()
        self.durationPicker.setSelectedItemIndex(durationPickerIndex)
    }
}


@IBAction func durationPickerChanged(value: Int) {
    print("durationPickerChanged: \(value)")
    //...
}
```

when running this code, the console shows the following output:

```
self.durationPickerHidden=false
direct setting durationPicker Index to 24
animation setting durationPicker Index to 24
durationPickerChanged: 21
```

You see the picker changed to an index 21 that I did not set.

I tried many variations of this code, the crucial part seems to be the following:

- When I am running without animation, everything works fine. (index 24 is selected)
- it makes no difference if setFocus() is inside or outside the animation.
- it makes no difference if setSelectedItemIndex is inside or outside the animation
- when self.durationPicker.setHeight(self.durationPickerHeigth) is inside the animation (which is critical for the visual effect), then the picker selects this arbitrary Item 21.

Does anybody know how I can set the height of a picker with animation and still be in control which item is selected?

Answer (score 1):

I found the following workaround that makes the problem invisible:

```
var durationPickerWorkaroundNecessary = false
func setDurationPickerVisibility(duration: NSTimeInterval) {
    print ("self.durationPickerHidden=\(self.durationPickerHidden)")
    animateWithDuration(duration) {
        if self.durationPickerHidden {
            self.durationPicker.resignFocus()
            self.durationPicker.setHeight(0.0)
            self.durationPicker.setHidden(self.durationPickerHidden)
        } else {
            self.durationPicker.setHeight(self.durationPickerHeigth)
            print ("animation setting durationPicker Index to \(self.durationPickerIndex)")
            self.durationPicker.setSelectedItemIndex(self.durationPickerIndex)
            self.durationPicker.setHidden(self.durationPickerHidden)
            self.durationPicker.focus()
            self.durationPickerWorkaroundNecessary = true
        }
    }
}


@IBAction func durationPickerChanged(value: Int) {
    print("durationPickerChanged: \(value)")
    if durationPickerWorkaroundNecessary == true {
        durationPickerWorkaroundNecessary = false
        if durationPickerIndex != value {
            print("durationPickerChanged: fixing value")
            durationPicker.setSelectedItemIndex(durationPickerIndex)
            return
        }
    }
    durationPickerIndex = value


    //...
}
```

The basic idea is to ignore the first change event after the animation.
Ugly, but it works.

Setting focus() inside the animation makes the animation smoother.

Comment: Did you ever find any other way around this? I would hate to do something like you did above because this seems like a bug and if Apple ever fixes it then it seems your code might break.
I'm glad I found this post thought because I couldn't figure out why the value I set wasn't taking, and it turned out to be the setHeight call changing the value back on me.  What I ended up doing was using a dispatch_after call to set the value .05 seconds after setting the height.  Not sure if that would work with an animation though.

Comment: Not in watchOS 2.x. I'll revisit in watchOS 3. Due to an unrelated severe "feature" in iOS 9.x this app didn't make it in the app store so far.

Comment: As far as this issue, I just found out that in my case it does not happen if the initial height (as defined in the storyboard) is above a certain size.

Comment: Mine is initially hidden, which means height == 0 :-(

Comment: I meant I noticed if I set it to height 40 in the storyboard and in the awakeWithContext I set it to 0 when I don't want it visible, then the issue doesn't happen.  That is all I needed in my case fortunately, but I went further and I see that the issue still occurs when setting the height back to 40 again.  Actually from rereading your code, I guess you already knew that the problem only occurred when increasing the height.  I guess your workaround is best.  I feel your pain though, I always hate to write hacks like that.